# upload speed is too slow windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

When connecting the ethernet cable directly to my PC the download speed is 50Mb/sec and upload - 0.5Mb/sec

But when the same cable connected to a laptop(also Win 7) the speed is around 50Mb both ways.

Also my VMWare Virtual Machine shows 50Mb/20Mb. The VMWare Network Adapter type is Bridget. **The Virtual Machine installed on my PC**. This part of the problem confuses me the most! The host machine has upload speed 0.5 Mb and the Virtual Machine that runs inside it has upload speed 20Mb.

How do I troubleshoot this issue? What settings should I check first of all?

Comment: First: Try a new cable.  Second: Try it in Safe Mode with networking.  Third: Try it from another OS (Linux LiveCD or alike).  What does VMware have to do with this exactly?

Comment: How are you testing your speeds and to what exactly? Your post is confusing so trying to answer is difficult, they are many possible answers to your "problem", but the problem is not clearly defined.

Comment: Guys, sorry if the post is confusing. Just tell me what statements to update and I will fix it. Regarding cable - I plug exactly this cable to my latptop and my speed is good. I plug this cable to my PC and the speed is low(only upload speed). Regarding the Virtual Machine - I just thought it worth mentioning that Virtual Machine that runs on my PC get's high speed(both download and upload).

Comment: It really looks like some software is limiting the upload speed on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160360/246719). Reposting the answer:

The answer turned out to be the **Large Send Offload (IPv4)** setting on my NIC. It was enabled by default. When I disabled it my work upload speed jumped to 12+ Mbps. It appears that if the infrastructure (e.g. routers, switches) don't support this option the transmits become "bursty" and slow down. My home router (an Apple Airport Extreme) apparently does support this option.

To disable, go to Start->Control Panel->Device Manager->Network adapters->[your LAN adapter name], right-click then select Properties->Click **Configure** button. On the **Advanced** tab, find property Large Send Offload (IPv4) and change its value to Disabled then click OK.